# Mantener la pestaña seleccionada (activa) después del Submit

Tags: javascript, html5, bootstrap-4

Tengo un formulario con html y bootstrap 4, nav nav-tabs. Quisiera saber, ¿cómo mantengo activa o seleccionada la pestaña después del Submit? Ello debido a que regresa a la primer pestaña cada que recorre el submit mi formulario. 
De antemano gracias.

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
 <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html" />
 <meta name="author" content="" />
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


 <title>Sin título 2</title>
</head>

<body>

<form id="control" name="control" method="post" action=""  accept-charset="UTF-8">                                    
<div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">          
                <ul id="tabsJustified" class="nav nav-tabs">                    
                    <li class="nav-item"><a href="" data-target="#tab2" data-toggle="tab" class="nav-link text-uppercase active" style="font-family:Arial black;size: 27px;">PARTES <i class="fas fa-users fa-lg"></i></a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a href="" data-target="#tab3" data-toggle="tab" class="nav-link text-uppercase" style="font-family:Arial black;size: 27px;">DATOS GENERALES <i class="fas fa-id-card fa-lg"></i></a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a href="" data-target="#tab4" data-toggle="tab" class="nav-link text-uppercase" style="font-family:Arial black;size: 27px;">TIEMPOS <i class="fas fa-clock fa-lg"></i></a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a href="" data-target="#tab5" data-toggle="tab" class="nav-link text-uppercase" style="font-family:Arial black;size: 27px;">AUDIO Y VIDEO <i class="fas fa-video fa-lg"></i></a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a href="" data-target="#tab6" data-toggle="tab" class="nav-link text-uppercase" style="font-family:Arial black;size: 27px;">CONCLUSIONES <i class="fas fa-clipboard-check fa-lg"></i></a></li>
                </ul>                
                <br />
                
                <div id="tabsJustifiedContent" class="tab-content" style="background-color: #E8DAD42">
                    
                    <div id="tab2" class="tab-pane fade active show" style="font-size:16.5px; text-align:center; font-family: Roboto;font-weight: bold;">                        
             111111                             
                    </div>
                    
<div id="tab3" class="tab-pane fade" style="font-size:16.5px; text-align:center; font-family: Roboto;font-weight: bold;">
  222222
  </div>
                              
     <div id="tab4" class="tab-pane fade" style="font-size:16.5px; text-align:center; font-family: Roboto;font-weight: bold;">
        333333
                    </div>
                          
<div id="tab5" class="tab-pane fade" style="font-size:16.5px; text-align:center; font-family: Roboto;font-weight: bold;">
         44444
            </div>
                          
         <div id="tab6" class="tab-pane fade" style="font-size:16.5px; text-align:center; font-family: Roboto;font-weight: bold;">
   5555
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div> 
        </div>
                
                
        <div class="contenedor">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg btn-block" name="update">GUARDAR </button>   
        </div>    
 </form>   
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Al parecer usas ajax, por lo tanto puedes enviar los datos asincronicamente

```
$('#control').on('submit', function(e) { 
    e.preventDefault(); //Previene que se envié el formulario
    //puedes colocar aqui tu código para bloquear el botón y notificar
    //al usuario que se están enviando los datos
    $.ajax({
        url: '/url',
        type: 'post'
        data: $(this).serialize()
    }).done(function(res) {
        console.log(res); //Código ejecutado correctamente
    }).fail(function(err) {
        console.log(err); //hubo un error
    }).always(function() {
        console.log('finalizado'); //Se ejecuta al finalizar la petición
        //aqui puedes desbloquear el botón de submit
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Esto es lo que hace el boton submit.

```html
<?php
require_once 'conexionMySQL3.php';

       $conn = dbConnect();
    $OK = true;
    $msg = '';
       
function strtoupper_utf8($string){
    $string=utf8_decode($string);
    $string=mb_strtoupper($string);
    $string=utf8_encode($string);
    return $string;
}

 if (array_key_exists('update', $_POST)){     
    
  $sql = 'UPDATE audiencia a INNER JOIN causa c ON a.no_causa = c.no_causa 
                        SET c.carpeta_investigacion= ?,a.num_audiencia= ?
                                    WHERE a.id_audiencia = ?';
                                    
                                    
  $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
  $OK = $stmt->execute(array(strtoupper_utf8($_POST['carpeta_investigacion']),$_POST['num_audiencia'],$_GET['id']));
                                 
  $error = $stmt->errorInfo();
  if (!$OK) {
   echo $error[2];
            echo $OK;
  } else {
            echo "<script>";
   echo "alert('BITACORA DE SALA / AUDIO Y VIDEO ACTUALIZADA');";
   echo "</script>";
   header("refresh:0;bitacora_sala.php?causa=".$_GET['causa'].'&id='.$_GET['id']);
              exit;
  }
 }
?>
```

```
<?php
```

require_once 'conexionMySQL3.php';

```
   $conn = dbConnect();
   $OK = true;
   $msg = '';
```

function strtoupper_utf8($string){
    $string=utf8_decode($string);
    $string=mb_strtoupper($string);
    $string=utf8_encode($string);
    return $string;
}

```
if (array_key_exists('update', $_POST)){       

    $sql = 'UPDATE audiencia a INNER JOIN causa c ON a.no_causa = c.no_causa 
                    SET c.carpeta_investigacion= ?,a.num_audiencia= ?
                                WHERE a.id_audiencia = ?';


    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $OK = $stmt->execute(array(strtoupper_utf8($_POST['carpeta_investigacion']),$_POST['num_audiencia'],$_GET['id']));

    $error = $stmt->errorInfo();
    if (!$OK) {
        echo $error[2];
        echo $OK;
    } else {
        echo "<script>";
        echo "alert('BITACORA DE SALA / AUDIO Y VIDEO ACTUALIZADA');";
        echo "</script>";
        header("refresh:0;bitacora_sala.php?causa=".$_GET['causa'].'&id='.$_GET['id']);
                exit;
    }
}
```

?>